# Laravel 5 roles and permissions (Bican/Roles)

Tags: php, permissions, laravel-5, roles

I'm trying to get roles and permissions to work properly, but I can't seem to get this right. I get an error while seeding the database:

`[BadMethodCallException]
 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attachRole()`

I assume I'm doing something wrong, but I can't see what it would be.

```
use Bican\Roles;
use Bican\Roles\Models\Role;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        // Create admin
        $adminRole = Role::where('name', '=', 'Admin')->first();
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => 'Admin',
            'email' => 'email@domain.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('Password99')
        ]);
        $user -> attachRole($adminRole);
    }
}
```

What I try to use is this: https://github.com/romanbican/roles
I followed the installation instructions and all went well until I was going to test it. The roles table seeder runs fine, and I can see the roles in the database. But I cant assing roles to users.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't that `$user->attach($adminRole)` ?

Comment: Sounds like you didnt add the trait (and implement the interface) on your user model: https://github.com/romanbican/roles#hasroleandpermission-trait-and-contract

Comment: @steve I did that part too. Here is a screencap http://i.imgur.com/kPe07p1.png.
@JilsonThomas No, it says `attachRole()` in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out... I'm using `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;` when I need to use `use App\User;` Working now.